# Running Argpars but got this error SystemExit 2

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, argparse

I am trying to set up training arguments and parse but I got this error could anyone help please!

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Explore pre-trained AlexNet')
parser.add_argument(
    '--image_path', type=str,
    help='Full path to the input image to load.')
parser.add_argument(
    '--use_pre_trained', type=bool, default=True,
    help='Load pre-trained weights?')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

got this error
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--image_path IMAGE_PATH]
[--use_pre_trained USE_PRE_TRAINED]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-ff8e2476-e39b-4e40-b8f9-6b8113fe8f1f.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

Comment: What command did you type because it says: "unrecognized arguments: -f"

Comment: I have run it using colab! Do I need to use command line

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific here. Provide your steps for execution. Also, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593590/passing-commandline-argument-in-google-colab

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter notebook cell:

```
import sys
sys.argv
```

I get get

```
['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py',
 '-f',
 '/home/paul/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-7923bfd2-9f96-45cf-8b44-1859a2185715.json']
```

The Jupyter server is using the `sys.argv` to set up the communication channel with your kernel.  `argparse` parses this list too.

So `commandline` and `argparse` cannot be used to provide arguments to your notebook when run this way.

---

How did you start this script?  Did you even try to provide the commandline values that the script expected?

```
'--image_path' 
'--use_pre_trained'
```

If you did, you probably would have gotten a different parser's error, about 'unexpected arguments'.  That's coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Colab may this solution help you, this solution suggest to you to write argparse in the other python file [introduction-argparse-colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/anthony-agbay/introduction-to-python/blob/main/modules/introduction-argparse-pt1/introduction-argparse-pt1.ipynb#scrollTo=tct-WCbXJ1VJ)

```
%%writefile parsing.py

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Jupyter notebook code works like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--image_folder', type=str, default='/content/image', help='path to image folder')
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", required=False)
```

**You need to add in the end of " parser.add_argument " line ( This is the reason you are getting 'SystemExit: 2' error ):**

```
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)
```

in your case this should work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Explore pre-trained AlexNet')
parser.add_argument('--image_path', type=str, default='your_path', help='Full path to the input image.')
parser.add_argument('--use_pre_trained', type=bool, default=True, help='Load pre-trained weights?')
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now you can call:

```
image = args.image_path
```

Or

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(args.image_path)
```

Tested in Google colab